# Can virtual functions be C++20 coroutines?

Tags: c++20, coroutine, virtual-functions, c++-coroutine

The title says it all: Can virtual functions also be C++20 coroutines?

```
struct A {
    virtual std::generator<int> generate() const = 0; // std::generator: C++23
};

struct B : A {
    virtual std::generator<int> generate() const { ~~~~ }
};
```

?

Comment: What did the compiler say when you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines)

> Restrictions
> Coroutines cannot use variadic arguments, plain return statements, or placeholder return types (auto or Concept).
> Constexpr functions, constructors, destructors, and the main function cannot be coroutines.

Knowing how they work, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: The important part is that being a coroutine is an aspect of the function's _definition_, not its interface.  On the outside, a coroutine is just a function that immediately returns the advertised type (which is why constructors and destructors can't participate, as well as why they can't use C-style varargs).

Comment: Next up: Main as a coroutine, a study in insanity.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Note: coroutines don't have to "immediately" return anything.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: No, that's explicitly disallowed.

Comment: @NicolBolas: True; I just mean that the return value really is the value of the call and typically appears before the coroutine "does its real work".